# Gsheet app script for changing a background of a cell every 7 days starting on Tuesday

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I’m trying to figure out a script for gsheet that will allow me to alternate the cell background color of a set of dates with these conditions:

- Each week starts on a Tuesday
- weeks are 7 days long

Essentially, if I have 6 dates: 1/2, 1/3, 1/8, 1/9, 1/10 and 1/18, then 1/2, 1/3, and 1/8 are grey, 1/9, 1/10 are white and 1/18 is grey again.

Initially tried using conditional formatting and used `=isodd(weeknum(A1))` which will format each week but does not work for weeks starting on a diff day.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function for changing background color of a cell at midnight

```
function changeBackgroundColorOfACell(e) {
  const colors = ["gray","white","lightblue","yellow","brown","turquoise","lightred"];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveCell().setBackground(colors[e.day-of-week]);
}

function createtbtrigger() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "changeBackgroundColorOfACell").forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("changeBackgroundColorOfACell").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(0).create();
}
```

Save the functions and call the second one.